# Getting a "R session aborted" message when trying to connect to vertica using RJDBC

Tags: r, vertica, rjdbc

I'm trying to connect R to vertica and I'm getting a fatal error when I create the vDriver variable.  Please any help or direction you can give me to resolve this would be really helpful!

```
library(RJDBC)
library(plyr)
vDriver <- JDBC(driverClass="com.vertica.jdbc.Driver", classPath = "C:/Users/username/Desktop/vertica-jdbc-7.0.1-0.jar")
```

Comment: Hard to say for sure without any debug info. You could try to use `JDBC("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver")` and use ODBC instead if you have that set up since it looks like you are on Windows.

Comment: same problem with RJDBC sap hana driver

Comment: @mangodreamz Can you please post the solution to this as i am also trying the same and have posted the question here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50984530/how-to-connect-r-to-vertica-database-through-drivers)